# Delete bulk record from MySql table while passing array in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I want to pass as array of id's and with this array i want to delete multiple records from table in node js

Below code which i was trying but it's not working properly;

```
let deletedImageIds = [24081,222];

db.query(`delete from mx_product_images where productImageID in ?`, deletedImageIds, (err, res) => {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log("error: ", err);
                    callback(err, null); 
                    return;
                  }
                  callback(null, res);
                  return;
                })
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because MySQL can't understand javascript array/objects. so please convert this javascript array to a comma-separated string, then append to the original query.

```
let deletedImageIds = [24081,222];
let del_str = deletedImageIds.join();

db.query(`delete from mx_product_images where productImageID in (?)`, del_str, (err, res) => {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log("error: ", err);
                    callback(err, null); 
                    return;
                  }
                  callback(null, res);
                  return;
                })
```